# gRPC with Legacy .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

Everything I've seen around gRPC seems to be in Dotnet Core.

I'm unfortunately constrained to using .NET Framework as I'm working on a legacy app.

I'd like to add some gRPC endpoints to it.

Can this be done in any reasonable way?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-8.0#net-framework

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain tip: if you delete the /de-de/ portion of that URL: it works naturally for most people in their natural language

Comment: @MarcGravell oops, yearh, here's the un-localized link: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-8.0#net-framework

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain - That talks about a client, the client is actually going to be net 8, it's the server I need to be in Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Grpc.Core` pacakage contains the (legacy) unmanaged client and server code and can be used on .NET Framework; typical usage would be:

```cs
Server server = new Server
{
    Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", 10042, ServerCredentials.Insecure) },
    Services = {
        Calculator.BindService(calc),
        TimeService.BindService(clock),
    }
};
server.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Server running... press any key");
Console.ReadKey();
await server.ShutdownAsync();
```

A client would be more like:

```cs
var channel = new Channel("localhost", 10042, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
try
{
    var calc = new Calculator.CalculatorClient(channel);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        using var ma = calc.MultiplyAsync(new MultiplyRequest { X = i, Y = i });
        var calcResult = await ma.ResponseAsync;
        Console.WriteLine(calcResult.Result);
    }



    var clock = new TimeService.TimeServiceClient(channel);
    using var subResult = clock.Subscribe(new Empty());
    var reader = subResult.ResponseStream;
    while (await reader.MoveNext(default))
    {
        var time = reader.Current.Time;
        Console.WriteLine($"The time is now {time}");
    }
}
finally
{
    await channel.ShutdownAsync();
}
```

So: yes.

Comment: Can that be integrated nicely into OWIN or an ASP WebAPI?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater no; it is built on top of CHTTP2 - entirely separate and unmanaged IO layer

Answer (score 0):

Examples for the legacy C# implementation that works with .NET Framework can be found here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.46.x/examples/csharp

As Marc said, you need to use the Grpc.Core package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core